# Converting Url list to an ip?

Tags: php, javascript

Is there any program for converting list of Urls to an ip list ?
example:

```
site1.com  ip1
site2.com  ip2
site3.com  ip3
```

Answer (score 1):

php has dns lookup. there are lots of similar services on internet too

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php

Answer (score 1):

In php, you can call [dns_get_record](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php) to get the [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) records associated with a given hostname. Note that there each domain is associated with zero or more IPv4 as well as zero or more IPv6 addresses, so you may want to return an array of addresses instead. Nevertheless, here's

```
$domains = array('example.net', 'google.com', 'ipv6.google.com', 'example.404');
$ips = array_map(function($domain) {
    $records = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_AAAA);
    if (count($records) == 0) { // No IPv6 addresses, try IPv4
        $records = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_A);
        if (count($records) == 0) return false; // No mapping found
        return $records[0]['ip'];
    } else {
        return $records[0]['ipv6'];
    }
}, $domains);

var_export(array_combine($domains, $ips));
```

The output will be something like:

```
array (
  'example.net' => '2001:500:88:200::10',
  'google.com' => '209.85.148.105',
  'ipv6.google.com' => '2a00:1450:4001:c01::93',
  'example.404' => false,
)
```

Comment: i appreciate all of you for the help but i was looking at the code and if i need to get the domains name from hosts.txt file how could be the code will? <?php
$hosts = Array(
   'www.google.com',
   'www.stackoverflow.com',
   'kera.name'
);

$ips = Array();
foreach ($hosts as $host) {
   if (($ip = gethostbynamel($host)) != FALSE)
      $ips[] = $ip;
   else
      $ips[] = Array();
}

print_r($ips);
?>

Comment: @Amenda Sorry, I don't quite follow - that code is Tomalaks answer and unrelated to mine. If you want to have `/etc/hosts` to affect your results, have to either parse it by hand or use [gethostbynamel](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) instead of `dns_get_records` (which will only return IPv4 addresses). As of writing, php does not yet have a `getnameinfo` function.

Answer (score 1):

Use php function [gethostbyname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) — Get the IPv4 address corresponding to a given Internet host name **

```
<?php
$ip = gethostbyname('www.google.com');

echo $ip;
?>
```

You might be looking into something like this:

```
$domains = "site1.com site2.com site3.com";
foreach(explode(" ", $domains) as $domain)
{
    echo $domain ." ".gethostbyname($domain);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

if the domain has more than one ip (ex: google.com) you can use [gethostbynamel](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php) — Get a list of IPv4 addresses corresponding to a given Internet host name .

```
<?php
$hosts = gethostbynamel('www.example.com');
print_r($hosts);
?>


Array
(
    [0] => 74.125.225.19
    [1] => 74.125.225.16
    [2] => 74.125.225.18
    [3] => 74.125.225.20
    [4] => 74.125.225.17
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of searching on the internet doesn't harm anyone, found on php.net through Google search "ip from url php":

[gethostbyname()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php)

Comment: i mean if i can get the hosts from file called hosts.txt and then printed just the ip in lines?

Answer (score 0):

Start by extracting just the host from your URLs, then use [`gethostbynamel`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php) if you don't care about IPv6 (tsk):

```
<?php
$hosts = Array(
   'www.google.com',
   'www.stackoverflow.com',
   'kera.name'
);

$ips = Array();
foreach ($hosts as $host) {
   if (($ip = gethostbynamel($host)) != FALSE)
      $ips[] = $ip;
   else
      $ips[] = Array();
}

print_r($ips);
?>
```

Note that there are potentially multiple IPs per host.

Neither ideone nor codepad seem to have DNS resolution set up such that I could provide a live demo for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = fopen("hosts.txt","r") or exit("Unable to open file");

while(!feof($file))
{
    $host = fgets($file);
    echo "IP: " . gethostbyname($host) . "<br />";
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: thanks abbas but when i tested ,it print all the urls (domains name) except the last url of hosts.txt it is an ip

Comment: Then check the record before calling the function gethostbyname(). If the record is a hostname, use the function, otherwise just print the record as it is an IP already. :)

Comment: ^__^ thanks abbas it would be greatfully if you posted the solved of my problem becasue i didnot understand you please ! 
IP: xxxx.com
IP: xxxx.org
IP: xxxx.com
IP: site.com
IP: site1.com
IP: 63.247.140.166

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? Just make sure you have a textfile 'hosts.text'. The first line of code opens the file and the while loop reads each line in the file and calls the function. But like others said: one host might have zero or multiple ip-addresses so ot's better to return an array containg zero, one or multipple addresses for the host. Check other reactions in this topic for some code.

Comment: let me specify my problem please you dont understand me maybe i am sure that i have put the sites in hosts.txt but when i try to run the code you gave me it is just get one ip for the last website in the text and i dont want that i want get all the ips of the urls in hosts.txt
example 'IP: flyertalk.com
IP: zagg.com
IP: adventuregamers.com
IP: kidsdinos.com
IP: 174.46.134.54'

Comment: Did you put each url of the site on a separate line in the file?

Comment: i am sorry for tiring you ,yes i have put them please and thats what i want, i want the ips seperated in lines

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function [gethostbyname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php) to resolve a host name to IPv4 address.

Example:

```
$hosts = file("hosts.txt");
$fp = fopen("hostsip.txt", "w");

foreach ($hosts as $host) {
  fwrite($fp, str_pad(trim($host), 20) . gethostbyname(trim($host)) . "\r\n");
}

etc...
```

Comment: Or actually the host name part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is just to process a file and produce an array like

```
array('site1.com' => 'ip1', 'site2.com' => 'ip2', 'site3.com' => 'ip3');
```

Then this piece of code should work (sorry, can't check it right now, but this should work):

```
$data = file_get_contents('hosts.txt');
$lines = explode("\n", $data);
$result = array();

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $pieces = explode(' ', trim($line));
    if (!empty($pieces[0]) && !empty($pieces[1])) {
        $result[trim($pieces[0])] = trim($pieces[1]);
    }
}
```

So in $result you will have the array with urls as the keys and ips as the values.

EDIT: the code written in PHP

Comment: thanks itsmee but it would be hard if i do that because i have about 57 urls and i want the ips just printed in seprated line just like this  site http://freelabs.info/UrlToIpOnline.aspx